# Singleton networking object gives error on second call

Tags: java, network-programming, singleton

Communication class of which singleton object will be created:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Communication {

    private static Communication mInstance = null;

    private static final String REQUEST_LOGIN = "Login";    

    private BufferedOutputStream socketOutput = null;
    private PrintWriter printOut = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private Scanner reader = null;  

    private Communication()
    {
        //connect to server using loopback address
        try{
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4242);
            //set inputs and out puts
            socketOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            printOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            reader = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch( UnknownHostException uhe){
            uhe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch( IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   public static Communication getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new Communication();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }   

    //sample method for requesting login
    public boolean login(String u, String p){       
        try{            
            String username = u;
            String password = p;                

            printOut.printf("%s!%s@%s\n", REQUEST_LOGIN, username, password);
            int loginStatus = reader.nextInt();
            if (loginStatus == 1){
                    socketOutput.close();
                    socket.close();                 
                    return true;}
            else{
                socketOutput.close();
                socket.close();             
                return false;
            }           
        }
        catch( IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Another class which will be using singleton object repeatedly:

```
public class Go{
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Communication.getInstance().login("user", "password");
        Communication.getInstance().login("user", "password");
    }
}
```

First call is alright and authentication happens. Second call invokes error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Communication.login(Communication.java:49)
    at Go.main(Go.java:7)
```

How can I use that object repeatedly ?

Comment: Looks like the error is happening on `reader.nextInt()`. Try calling `hasNextInt()` before to make sure there is a value available.

Comment: I guess it's not available, because when implemented on Android it shows - java.util.NoSuchElementException at the same spot. But why it becomes unavailable on the second call and is okay on first one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login method closes the socket, on second call the scanner works on a dead input stream. Something in your application flow is broken.

The communicator is a singleton, and you break it because you invalidate all it's assets in the login method. The getInstance() method finds the singleton still set (because you do not set the singleton null at the end of login) and returns you the dead object.

Then scanner tries to readInt on a closed socket's input stream. I suppose that is not supposed to work.